# how to format percent with decimal using angular2 createNumberMask from text-mask

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

I am using [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/addons) for angular 2 to format a percent with a decimal. To do this I use the createNumberMask addon. When I try to format a string with a decimal into a percent I get a run-time error cannot ready property 'test' of undefined. Below is an example of how I am formatting the mask.

```
let percentMask = createNumberMask({
        prefix: '',
        suffix: '%',
        allowDecimal: true
    });
```

Using the above mask, I then call the function to return my mask array as follows

```
let mask = percentMask('4.5');
```

I then pass this mask to conformToMask as follows:

```
let conformed = conformToMask('4.5', mask, {guide:false});
```

This throws the following Runtime Error 'Error in :0:0 caused by: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined.

What is the correct way to implement the above functionality to allow a user to enter a percentage with a decimal and have it formatted correctly. i.e the user enters 4.5 which then appears as 4.5% in the UI.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution for this?

Comment: @eyalhakim did you?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug. [You can see a discussion about it here](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/issues/492). I've managed to get around the issue by removing the `'[]'` elements that are created by the function returned from `createNumberMask`:

```
let percentMask = createNumberMask({
    prefix: '',
    suffix: '%',
    allowDecimal: true
});

let mask = percentMask('4.5');
mask = mask.filter((val) => val != '[]');   // <-- this removes the '[]' elements

let conformed = conformToMask('4.5', mask, {guide:false});
```